# eventDrop callback date seems off by 1 day for the all-day use case

Tags: fullcalendar

I am printing event.start to the console upon eventDrop. When I drag an event to an all-day slot, the dates are off by a day, when I drag a normal agenda hour the date seems fine.

Example:
    http://jsfiddle.net/FxFba/361/

Drag event one to an allDay (6/2) positions and note the console log - Sun Jun 01 2014 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

Now drag to a time agenda slot (6/2 7am) and notice the console log - Mon Jun 02 2014 07:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

Are all days rolling back to the previous day for its start? Or am I missing something obvious?

```
fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
timezone: 'local',
editable: true,
defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
eventDrop : function(event,jsEvent,ui,view){
     console.log(event.start.toDate());  
},
events: [
    {
        title  : 'event1',
        start  : '2014-06-01'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event2',
        start  : '2014-06-06',
        end    : '2010-06-07'
    }
]
}
```

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Your code excerpt here on SO implements the eventDrop event, your jsFiddle, the eventDragStop event. If in jsFiddle you change it back to eventDrop, the start date seems correct...

Comment: Sorry for the typo. However, I did change it to eventDrop and still saw misleading results. http://jsfiddle.net/FxFba/362/

Comment: first drag: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1HgsGDN11kzSGQ3VXdqRG4yWVE/edit next drag: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1HgsGDN11kzcE9hREFydzdsTzg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, the issue has something to do with the timezones. You are in Pacific time (PDT), which is -7 hours compared to UTC. So the 1st of June at midnight -7 hours = 31st of May at 17:00 : which is what we see in your screenshot.
I am in GMT +2, therefore the date remains the same (1st of June) but the full day event starts at 2 AM for me instead of midnight as you can see on that screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/2clrJg3.jpg (the 2nd drag, on the "toDate()" function console log.
You can display the UTC time with toISOString() though:  http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/FxFba/363/

Comment: Unfortunately I am not very 'skilled' with manipulating timezones... there might be some helpful info for you there: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/timezone/timezone/

Comment: Thanks for the input Slyvain, the toISOString seems to help. I do admit that this is still a mystery to me why the toDate would be ambiguous on the same date column in the week agenda view.

Comment: Indeed, there might be more info with this: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/Moment/

Answer (score 2):

FullCalendar has Moment.js as a dependency, and Moment, in turn, has a method .utc(), which when used to format your date, can counteract the adding and subtracting of hours due to your timezone difference.

Something like

```
var configuredTime = moment(date._d).utc().format("MM-DD-YYYY");
```

may work for you, if you are using the drop callback:

```
drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {}
```

Check out

> http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/